# Ignore the value of an empty Attributes in the element LINQ C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, linq

I'm trying to retrieve values from an XML file and I find some values are empty. 
`textBox6, textBox7, textBox14` corresponding element attribute values are empty/null. The error message is `Null reference error was unhanded` . How can fix this??

```
private void DisplayFile(string path)
    {

        var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
        var conn = doc.Root.Element(ns + "connection");

        textBox1.Text = conn.Element(ns + "sourceId").Value;


        var doc1 = XDocument.Load(path);
        var ns1 = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();         
        var conn1 = doc.Root.Element(ns1 + "connectionContext");


    }
```

Comment: Which line is it crashing on?

Comment: @Arion: `<organization /><field /><description />` if any attribute value is empty in the element then it's crashing.

Comment: Why don't you want to check *if(conn.Element(ns + "sourceId")!=null)* ?

Comment: @Likurg: Is it possible to check the element itself instead of checking for each and every attribute value??

Comment: @KarthikRANGARAJ Look at answer of Stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a given element is not present in the XML `foo.Element("someNode")` will return null. When accessing `.Value` you get a NullReferenceException.

In order to avoid this NullReferenceException you need to check if the element is not null.

Example with *contextType*:

```
var contextType = conn1.Element(ns + "contextType");
if (contextType != null)
{
  textBox15.Text = contextType.Value;
}
```

**Update:**

You try to load the *connectionContext* node from the root element. But this node is a child of the *source* node. You need to first load this node:

```
var source = doc.Root.Element(ns + "source");
var conn1 = source.Element(ns + "connectionContext");
```

Comment: Looks like it should have worked to me, is there a breakpoint being hit?

Comment: @Stefan:error at this line, `var contextType = conn1.Element(ns + "contextType");``Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: @KarthikRANGARAJ put your code inside if (conn1!=null) statement. I think you should find out why conn1 XElemenent is null.

Comment: @ xeondev: error is gone but still i couldn't get the values??

Answer (score 0):

I find your problem try this (i use string cause didn't want to make textboxes)

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Test\\stovfl.xml");
        var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

        var conn = doc.Root.Element(ns + "connection");
        string s1 = conn.Element(ns + "sourceId").Value;
        string s2 = conn.Element(ns + "username").Value;

        var conn1 = doc.Root.Element("source");

        var conn2 = conn1.Element("connectionContext");
        string s6 = conn2.Element(ns + "organization").Value;
        string s7 = conn2.Element(ns + "field").Value;

        string s14 = conn2.Element(ns + "description").Value;
        string s15 = conn2.Element(ns + "contextType").Value;
```

problem was that you have *connectionContext* in *source*, but try to find it in *Root*

Comment: @KarthikRANGARAJ Add you should to check all element like Stefan show you